# Ubuntu one in the cloud, not on the local hd

Tags: ubuntu-one

Ubuntu one takes up space on the local hard drive..

This is good for in many cases, but if you have a small hard drive (e.g. ssd) it does not make sense only to have as much cloud as you have local hard drive..

Does anyone know of any plans for ubuntu one to support a "move to cloud" feature in addition to the excellent file-synchronization?

I would love to make a feature request but do now know where...

Also, I know this is the point of bitcasa, but I like ubuntu one better, and would love to buy a lot of space and throw out the old external hd  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu One file sync is only a file synchronization service. So this will not be supported. The `~/Ubuntu One/` folder will always be synchronized. You can, however, achieve such a usage, by creating another synchronized folder on the server with the REST API, uploading files directly to the server with the REST API, and simply never choosing to synchronize that folder on the client side (or possibly, not even use the client on a machine where you want this behavior).

I don't know of any existing scripts or programs to simply do that, but you are certainly free to write one. Such a script could be integrated with the `Send to…` feature in Nautilus. The `duplicity` plug-in for Deja Dup, does do this, for uploading back-up files to Ubuntu One, as an example.

Comment: Great answer, possible with a lot of tinkering, but still, if the feature was nicely build into the client, it would make ubuntu one a much stronger alternative to iCloud, DropBox, and so forth...